# Use IP camera with OPEN CV without internet connection (direct connection to pc)

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0, infrared

I am sorry, this might not be the correct platform to ask this kind of question  but I couldn't think of any other place .

I for one of my project I need to capture some video footage from an outdoor camera using open cv. Actually, its a part of a bigger project where another signal triggers the camera. Since the camera will be located outside, I am looking for weather proof night vision enabled USB cameras that I can easily control via OPENCV. However I cannot find any descent USB camera and most of the websites show IP cameras. My problem is that the installation will be at a site where there is no internet so I cannot use internet. Can anybody please suggest if and how these IP cameras can be connected to the PC and be controlled via OPEN CV or else suggest some websites where I can get descent outdoor USB IR cameras.

I have also tried the NOIR Raspi camera but the quality is not very good and I think the range will also not be very good. Moreover running OPEN CV on RpI is very slow even for simple video recording.

Comment: Why can't you attach an Ethernet cable to an IP camera and to your Raspberry Pi which has an Ethernet port? Why can't you attach a client mode dongle to a camera and use your Raspberry Pi's WiFi? Why do you want to use OpenCV if it is too slow?

Comment: Hi, The Pi's wifi will be connected to an internet connection (which is very limited at the location, so my wifi will not be free). Well , earlier the plan was to use a PICamera with its library but the images it captured were not very good, but now I think we will use a laptop instead so we can run OPEN CV easily and do some computing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to that thread for how to use IP cameras with open CV. I didn't try it personally, but a simple google search got me that. http://answers.opencv.org/question/133/how-do-i-access-an-ip-camera/

Answer (score 0):

To access an IP camera is very simple, you just need this line:

```
  cv2.VideoCapture("rstp://ipaddress:port/blahbla")
```

Now, if you dont have internet the IP camera as the PI should be on the same network, you can have a wireless router with no internet.
If you dont have a wireless router you can create a hotspot on your PI so you can connect the Camera directly to the PI, alot of IP cameras support hotspot so you can connect your pi to them.